# Which FTA Install package do I need to DL?

Tags: fault-tolerance, tivoli-work-scheduler

We are running an End-2-End configuration with TWSzOS as the MDM. The MDM & all of the current FTA's are 8.5.1 and I'm attempting to upgrade everything, but I have a current request to install a new FTA and I don't want to install another out of support 8.5.1 Agent. The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out which install package I need. I'm only going as high as 9.2 because that's as high as our Service Provider can go right now. Do I need the IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler for z/OS Agent or the IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler Agent ? I've DL'd both and when I unzip them, the z/OS Agent zip seems to reference a zCentric Agent install. We need an FTA and the IBM TWS Agent zip references an FTA. But I just want to make sure I'm giving the Unix SA's the right package.

Answer (score 0):

`IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler for z/OS Agent` is only for zCentric Agent (this has a different license with a lower price).

For legacy end-to-end based on FTA you need the full package `IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler Agent`

Comment: That was what I thought Franco, but as I said, I wanted to make sure I was passing the correct package to the SA to install. Thank you very much sir !